# Очиcтка повторяющихся значений во вложенном массиве,

Tags: php, массивы

есть массив такого вида

```
[181] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 181
        [name] => Страна происхождения
        [position] => 181
        [in_filter] => 1
        [is_slider] => 0
        [options] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [product_id] => 4454
                        [feature_id] => 181
                        [value] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Венгрия
                            )

                        [count] => 2
                    )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [product_id] => 3913
                        [feature_id] => 181
                        [value] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Австрия33
                                [1] => Россия
                            )

                        [count] => 1
                    )

                [2] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [product_id] => 812
                        [feature_id] => 181
                        [value] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Россия
                                [1] => Корея
                            )

                        [count] => 1
                    )

                [4] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [product_id] => 2145
                        [feature_id] => 181
                        [value] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Россия
                            )

                        [count] => 10
                    )

            )

    )

[190] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 190
        [name] => Источник питания
        [position] => 190
        [in_filter] => 1
        [is_slider] => 0
        [options] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [product_id] => 3913
                        [feature_id] => 190
                        [value] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Аккумуляторы/Сеть 220В
                            )

                        [count] => 13
                    )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [product_id] => 812
                        [feature_id] => 190
                        [value] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Аккумуляторы/Сеть 220В/Сеть авто
                            )

                        [count] => 2
                    )

                [2] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [product_id] => 5470
                        [feature_id] => 190
                        [value] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Батарейки
                            )

                        [count] => 2
                    )

                [3] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [product_id] => 5472
                        [feature_id] => 190
                        [value] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Батарейки АА
                            )

                        [count] => 1
                    )
            )
    )
...
```

нужно очистить его от повторяющихся значений value во вложенном массиве options
В данном случае это 'Россия'.
 подскажите пожалуйста как это провернуть а то голову себе я уже сломал..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант навскидку

```
function filter($array, &$foundOptions)
{
    return array_filter($array, function ($value) use (&$foundOptions) {
        $isFound = isset($foundOptions[$value]);
        if (!$isFound) {
            $foundOptions[$value] = 0;
        } else {
            $foundOptions[$value]++;
        }
        return !$isFound;
    });
}

foreach ($array as $object) {
    $foundOptions = array();
    if ($object->options) {
        //Фильтрует повторяющиеся значения начиная со второго нахождения
        foreach($object->options as $option) {
            if (is_array($option->value)) {
                $option->value = filter($option->value, $foundOptions);
            }
        }
        //Оставляем только значения, которые нашлись > 1 раза
        $foundOptions = array_filter($foundOptions);

        //Проходим еще раз и удаляем найденое > 1 раза
        foreach($object->options as $option) {
            if (is_array($option->value)) {
                $option->value = filter($option->value, $foundOptions);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вообщем все верно, спасибо, немного добавил обработку чтобы пустые массивы удалялись и дублирующиеся элементы удались по элементно а не все сразу